# D3.js callback during transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update a marker position by performing a callback as the position for the path is changed. What would be the best way to do this?

```
path
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
        .CALLBACK_I_WANT(function(a) {
          UPDATE_MARKER(a)
        })
        .duration(10000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

I want the marker to look like this:

http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/

Comment: Step 9 of the tutorial you linked shows you how to do this with `attrTween`.

Comment: it still only gets called once

Comment: The function you give to `attrTween` is called once - it should return a function which d3 will call many times until the transition is finished.

Comment: well that'll do it... lol. Thank you.